# Why does `pip freeze` result in an empty file?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I'm following the [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python) to deploy Django applications on Heroku.

In the 5th line of the code, it says `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but when I run it (from the `venv`), the `requirements.txt` file is empty! It produced 6-7 dependencies with the same code before.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what do you see when just run this command? you could see something?

Answer (score 5):

That probably means the dependencies are installed on your global environment.

Switch to the virtual environment, and install the dependencies manually using `pip install <dependency>` and then running `pip freeze` should output the dependencies.

Comment: I was using venv (activating it too) but I never thought of installing the dependencies myself beforehand. I will try that. Thanks,

Comment: I faced such an issue after Python 3 upgrade. My old way of doing `pip freeze`was not working anymore (empty list) . I suppose a path issue (surely need to update python (or PIP) path after its upgrade ; I have to document myself because I'm not sure how to do it) but after doing `python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`, I could see again the list of all my dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is for posterity*

- This could be because of pip being deprecated.So upgrade pip by using

```
python -m pip install -–upgrade pip
```

Then run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` as usually.This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error but I figured it out now. I had my virtual environment set up using PowerShell (preferred for sys commands) that has the dependencies installed but I was running the Python shell with the command "pip freeze > requuiremnts.txt". When I ran the same command on PowerShell then I got requirements.txt populated with dependencies.