# pip freeze > requirements.txt creates the text file but the file is empty

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

Okay so I want to host my discord bot in Heroku but for the requirements.txt  when I use the command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the Cmd it creates the file but with no text in it

Comment: what does `pip freeze` give as output? Also, if you're using `python3`, I recommend trying `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: the requirements file is still empty after using pip3 freeze > requirements.txt

Comment: Have you checked the output of `pip3 freeze` or `pip freeze`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`pip freeze\` result in an empty file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192651/why-does-pip-freeze-result-in-an-empty-file)

Answer (score 0):

You were likely on your global environment, so your virtual environment has no dependencies installed. To fix:

Start your virtual environment (on Mac/Linux)

1. Navigate to the folder containing your .py files in the Terminal
2. python3 -m venv venv
3. source venv/bin/activate

This isn't ideal, but 1-by-1 install your dependencies using "pip install <dependency_name>". You can find your dependency names usually by looking at your "import " statement at the top of your python file. Alternatively, you can find them using:

python3 <app_name.py>

The error message that results in the Terminal will show you the missing dependency.

If "pip3 install <dependency_name>" doesn't work, search on PyPi for the correct name to install. Sometimes they vary.